# Securing Restful Web Services with Spring Security and OAuth2 (Spring Security + OAuth2 + Spring Rest)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I am very new to Spring security and Spring OAuth .
My requirement is to create a Java application with Spring security and Spring Oauth in the project. After searching on the internet I have found out this link 
http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html

I have few questions in it:

1)I have seen Spring security.xml and in that there is this code
    // please look at this code

```
<oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
        </oauth:authorization-server>
```

Do I need to have a oAuth server running in my system and I need to give details for that server in these lines provided .

If yes which server I have to use , Is it a downloadable  .exe file or just a depedency in maven will be fine to act as a server .

Please go through the example link I have given above and let me know If I import that project in my system and run it  ,Shall I assume that I am running Application with Spring security and Outh application.

Please help me in giving as much as information on these concepts as I am new and stuck...

Comment: You don't need any external server. If you want to provide two security mechanism for your application. Then you just need to implement OAuth mechanism within your application to access it either by Basic form based authentication or by OAuth access token.

Comment: So you mean to say if I only execute the project given in the above link  that is enough which means I have managed to use the( Spring security +Spring Oauth).